# Extracting user data from stackoverflow using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm pretty new to this web scraping (Data extraction) stuff. I want to extract the user's reputation from his stackoverflow account. I'm using Selenium. I've successfully logged in but I can't get the data from the next url, which is http://stackoverflow.com

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')

username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("emailID")
password.send_keys("password")

browser.find_element_by_name("submit-button").click()

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)

print browser.current_url
```

It works, I get redirected to the next page, but the last command still prints: 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

Thanks in advance. I'm sure I'm missing something little.

Comment: Use the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user), that's what it's for.

Comment: @LukasGraf The API tells about the information that's on the next page, i.e. User page, I've tried extracting the data using those tags. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes some time to update the `browser.current_url` after redirecting. You can use either `browser.refresh()` or `time.sleep()` to get the updated value.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')
username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys("emailID")
password.send_keys("password")
browser.find_element_by_name("submit-button").click()
browser.refresh()
print browser.current_url
```

Hope, the output of the below code could help you understand this better.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')
username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys("emailID")
password.send_keys("password")
browser.find_element_by_name("submit-button").click()

for i in range(5):
    print browser.current_url, " - loop ", i
    time.sleep(1)
print browser.current_url
```

Comment: I need your help on another thing
reputation = browser.find_element_by_class_name("reputation")
Why is this code returning this: 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6324aa926438c0c8ff58c9bd8b1f73c4", element="0.19992890885383097-1")>

Comment: Your asking selenium to  `find_element`, so what you're getting back is a web element. You should use something like `reputation = browser.find_element_by_class_name("reputation").text` if you want the text inside of the element.